# x-editable post render bug?

Tags: javascript, x-editable

I have the code below to init x-editable. The problem is the post render part. When clicking the input I don't need the setTimeout to set focus/select; but when calling `price_to_change.editable('show');` the post render function still runs; but I need setTimeout for the select to happen

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';     

$('.xeditable').editable({
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.isNumeric(value) == '' && $(this).data('validate-number')) {
            return 'Only numbers are allowed';
        }
    },
    success: function(response, newValue) {
          $("#register_container").html(response);
    },
});


$('.xeditable').on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    editable.input.postrender = function() {

        //setTimeout is only needed when calling .editable('show') as shown below
        setTimeout(function() {
     editable.input.$input.select();
    }, 10);
};


var price_to_change = $('#register a[data-name="price"]').first();
price_to_change.editable('show');
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some syntax between the postrender statement and the last two lines shown here. See http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/65m708td

Comment: I don't see a difference in your fiddle vs what I have. The code runs fun without syntax errors